# How to do VLOOKUP in my PowerBI table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi, dax

Gentlemen,  in my table I have a column CC (Number of Contracts), and another column "DATE" with the dates of each contract, but I want to make a comparison (Something like a PROCV in Excel), where I check in my column CC if  have the same contract numbers as the previous days or no. This way I can know exactly if there were new hires or if there were any terminated contracts. That is, what I need is a DAX formula or some mechanism that can be used to carry out this verification, such as an "IF", IF in my CC column there is a contract for more than the day before, insert it in the column "NEW CONTRACT" , otherwise "CLOSED".

Image below of my table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To compare the number of contracts in one day to the number of contracts on the previous day in PowerBI, you can use the `CALCULATE` and `FILTER` functions together in a calculated column. Here's an example of how you can use these functions to create a calculated column that shows whether the number of contracts on a given day is the same as the previous day:

1. Open your PowerBI report and select the table you want to add the calculated column to.
2. Click the Modeling tab in the ribbon, and then click the New Column button.
3. In the formula bar, type the following formula to create a calculated column:

```
  =CALCULATE(
       COUNT(CC[Number of Contracts]),
       FILTER(
           ALL(CC),
           CC[Date] = MAX(CC[Date]) - 1
       )
   )
```

The formula above uses the `CALCULATE` function to count the number of contracts on the previous day, and uses the `FILTER` function to select only the rows with the previous day's date.

Once you've created the calculated column, you can use an `IF` statement to compare the number of contracts on the current day to the number of contracts on the previous day, and show "NEW CONTRACT" or "CLOSED" in the resulting column. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
  =IF(
        [Number of Contracts] = [Number of Contracts (Previous Day)],
        "CLOSED",
        "NEW CONTRACT"
   )
```

The formula above used the `IF` function to compare the values in the Number of Contracts column to the values in the Number of Contracts (Previous Day) column. If the values are the same, it shows "CLOSED" in the resulting column. If the values are different, it shows "NEW CONTRACT" in the resulting column.

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Hello, that way it even worked using CALCULATE and FILTER makes the count, that way I can see the amount of contracts between the current and previous day, but I need him to check the contracts of the previous and current day, and describe if another contract was added as "NEW CONTRACT", and if any of the contracts from the previous day are gone on the current day then "CONTRACT ENDED". the way you exemplified in IF, him it is applying the value to all data, and that's not what I want. PICTURE OF AS IS WITH IF FORMULA: https://imgur.com/FRuUodb

Comment: If the question is not clear, please update the question with the additional detail that clarifies what you want.  Don't use comments to improve your question.